# Python: Passing a cursor back from a class for a dbi instance

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Trying to set up a class that will pass a database cursor back that I can use in various functions. The code below doesn't work

```
class create_db(object):   
    def __init__(self):
        import psycopg2 as pq
        self.cn = pq.connect('dbname=mydb user=me')
        self.cr = self.cn.cursor()
```

What I'd like to be able to do is

```
cur = create_db()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM table1;')
```

How can I change my code to address that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you'd like to do

```
class create_db(object):

    def __init__(self):
        import psycopg2 as pq
        self.cn = pq.connect('dbname=mydb user=me')
        self.cr = self.cn.cursor()

    def execute(self, query, *args):

        results = self.cr.execute(query, args)

        return results
```

now you can run something like

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column = ?;', (42,))
```

I can't remember off the top of my head but I think you'll want to omit the `;` at the end of your SQL statement.